# Harvesting hebrew names from a group of websites

Tags: jquery, hebrew, webharvest

I have the following website (hebrew):
http://www.daydeals.co.il/

It contains many links to external websites.
I want to write a jQuery script that will 
1) open all the links
2) collect the elements from all the open websites that contains the text "someText"
3) return a collection of all the elements from (2)

Could someone please guid me how to do this?

another question:
I tried to use the follwing jq selector:
alert($("div:contains('אביב')").text());

however when I browse this in any browser the hebrew turns to gibrish. Any way to over come this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) restrictions, the browser will not let you access a page on another domain via JavaScript. You will not be able to read from or collect data from an external website. You can do this with a server-side scripting like PHP, Perl or Java.

Do you have the Hebrew language version of the browser installed?

Comment: I have chrome supporting hebrew (All the menus are in hebrew). What else can i do ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Hebrew stuff, but if you want to open those pages and harvest some data from them take a look at the PHP function: [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). With this you can open a URL and parse through the HTML code.

Comment: Given a page with many links, how can I surf some links (say, that match a regex) via C# ? I don't need to actually open the links in the browser - just harvest an address info from the sires the links refer to.

Comment: Well I don't know C#, but you should be able to read the HTML contents of an external URL. I don't know how you'd parse that in C#, I'm assuming you can load the HTML into some DOM Document class and parse it that way, RegEx can be tricky since HTML code isn't very consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Web-Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/).
It's perfect for such tasks.

It's default working charset is UTF-8, so it should work with Hebrew sites, if they use UTF-8.
You also can define another charset in the [`<config>`](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#config) element.